# Different ways to weight probabilities or choose probability distribution

Tags: statistics, probability

Let's say I am a cake shop selling 3 types of cake. When a customer comes in, I can only put one of my cakes on display. **I choose the cake to display with uniform probability**, so each cake has a ~33% chance to be displayed. The customer purchases a cake depending on which cake is displayed with a probability of x<sub>A</sub>, x<sub>B</sub>, x<sub>C</sub>.

After doing an analysis for each cake, we know that when cake A is on display, it is bought 90% of the time. When cake B is on display, it is bought 70% of the time. When cake C is on display, it is bought 68% of the time.

| Cake | x<sub>i</sub> |
| --- | --- |
| A | 0.9 |
| B | 0.7 |
| C | 0.68 |

The question is, when the next customer walks in, what probability distribution should we use to **CHOOSE which cake to display next**, to (1) optimize customer purchase, but (2) without losing all sales for the less popular cakes, like B and C. So, we can't just put cake A on display 100% of the time to get our cake purchased with 90% of probability.

One method I have thought of is doing a weighting of probabilities. In this case, we would display cake A (0.9)/(0.9+0.7+0.68)=39% of the time.

| Cake | % of the time cake SHOULD be on display |
| --- | --- |
| A | 39% |
| B | 31% |
| C | 30% |

However, I think there might be a better way to do it, maybe taking into account purchase probability difference between A and B, etc? The % should add up to 100% for A, B, C.

Comment: Well, if all cakes sell for the same price, the greatest benefit to the seller is to always show the most popular cake unless it's sold out, then switch to the next most popular, etc. If you want a different kind of solution, you would have to quantify what it's worth to the seller to offer a less-popular cake. E.g. does the seller need to clear the inventory or something. By the way, my advice is to talk about the problem in terms of the actual context instead of trying to rephrase it in generic terms. There is almost always some context which changes the way you should go about it.

Comment: @Robert Dodier Thank you, the context I'm trying to tie it to is ads instead of cakes, and customer purchases = clicks. So I still need the less popular ads to have some visibility.

Comment: Well, if you are the person showing the ads (and someone else is paying you to do so), then it doesn't matter which one you pick, right? You are obliged to show each customer's ad a certain number of times or something like that. Conversely, if you are the customer, and you have multiple products, then the decision is more complex. My advice at this point is to take up this problem on math.stackexchange.com or stats.stackexchange.com and say that this is an advertising scenario and specifically for which agent (advertiser or advertiser's customer or someone else) you want to solve the problem.